# Cannot pass string variable to function to use eval

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use eval built in function within my function, if I do `eval(text)` or `eval("x * 2 + (x + 5)")` it could return the calculation but when I pass the text to my function it said `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`. I already cast it to string but still no avail

```
x = 1
text = "x * 2 + (x + 5)"

def test_func(x):
    res = eval(x)
    return res

test_func(text)
```

Comment: Think about what the value of `x` is inside and outside the function…

Comment: I already checked it and the value and the type is the same

Comment: You’re telling me `x` inside `test_func` is `1`‽ **Are you sure?!**

Comment: oh sorry, I thought the variable x outside the function and inside the function is different (local function variable)

Answer (score 1):

the argument x of the test_func is assumed to be an integer becasue you decalare before x=1. If you rename the argument it works:

```
x = 1
text = "x * 2 + (x + 5)"


def test_func(my_eval_string):
    res = eval(my_eval_string)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 'x' instead of 'text'.
Please check below one:

```
x = 1
text = "x * 2 + (x + 5)"

def test_func(text):
    res = eval(text)
    return res

print(test_func(text))
```